# How is n = 4q + r here?

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

If it says to divide quotient by 4 , then it should q/4 = r .

Comment: It says to divide $n$ by $4$; Euclidean division; $4$ goes into $n\;$ $q$ times with remainder $r$ (an integer)

Comment: But why 4q + 4r

Comment: Is not correct .

Comment: If you divide an integer $n$ by $4$ then you get a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$, with $0 \le r \le 3$, and you can say $n=4q+r$

Comment: @Henry I am not understanding why 4q

Comment: Let's take an example:  If $n=401$ then you can say $q=100$ and $r=1$ to give $401=4 \times 100 +1$. You want to do this so you can say $i^{403}=i^{401=4 \times 100 +1}=(i^4)^{100}i^1=i^1=i$

Comment: @Henry:  did you mean $40\color{red}1$ when you typed $403$?

Comment: @Henry Thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
When n is divided by 4 , the quotient is q.

Now the value n will be equal to 4q + r.It is easily understandable from the photo now I guess.

Example is :

$i^{135}$ = Here n is divided by 4 .

We are left with 3 as remainder.

Notice , 4q + 3 = 135 where q = 33

I hope it it clear now

Comment: Did you mean $q=3\color{red}3$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh yes.Thank you.

Comment: @srijannahar Thank you sir

Comment: It is "[Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)" (the last section, *"Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"*), not "stack exchange".

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like calling it "division". Instead, I would say that every $n\in \Bbb N$ can be *represented* as one (and only one) of the following: $$\begin{cases} 4q \\ 4q+1 \\ 4q+2 \\ 4q+3\end{cases}$$
that is, there is a $q\in \Bbb N$ and an $r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ such that $n=4q+r$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. That is what the question is driving at.

So, instead of calculating $i^n$, it calculates $i^{4q+r}=i^r$ because $i^4=1$, and so because $i^0=1, i^1=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i$, we can construct that: $$i^n=\begin{cases} 1 &n= 4q \\ i &n=4q+1 \\ -1 &n=4q+2 \\-i & n= 4q+3\end{cases}$$ which is the aim of this question, to generalise $i^n$

Comment: Oh yes.Thank you sir.Really easily understood now.